# XAMPP include_path not working

Tags: php, server, xampp, include-path, lampp

Im trying to require some php files into my main `index.php` but I get the following error:

> Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/steamauth/userinfo.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php
>   on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/steamauth/userinfo.php'
>   (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on
>   line 4

I tried the adding the following code:

```
set_include_path('/opt/lampp/htdocs/');
require dirname(__FILE__).'/steamauth/steamauth.php';
```

My include files steamauth.php and userinfo.php are at /opt/lampp/htdocs/steamauth/
I also tried setting the include_path in the `php.ini` file as well as adding it to my `.htaccess` file . And yes, I am sure that this is the correct path that I want to include. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you already try restarting your server? I ran into this problem using XAMPP. I edited the PHP.ini file and it did not work. When I restarted the XAMPP control panel, it worked fine with no modificaitons.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to add a new directory to php path. I solved it adding **double quotation marks** surrounding the include_path in the php.ini file.
Something like this:

```
include_path="C:\xampp\php\PEAR;c:\xampp\smarty\smarty-3.1.30\libs";
```

Comment: Single quotation marks here.  Perhaps you may need to edit your code

Answer (score 0):

What's your project folder structure ? Simply, try getting path right from index.php.

```
// /root/fooDir/userinfo.php
// /root/barDir/index.php

//in index.php
$dir = __DIR__ . '/../fooDir/userinfo.php';
```

Comment: nothing seems to be working. I thought that this is some problem with include_path in the php.ini , but changing it didnt solve the problem . How can i change the default XAMPP include_path variable ?